# is it possible to declare a variable with gremlin node values and later traverse using the variable

Tags: gremlin

I wonder if gremlin can handle a data structure graph where you can save the reference to the node in a variable and later use it to traverse neighboring nodes.

```
node1= g.V(1)   
node1.out('knows')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two confusing aspects here:

1. A Traversal is a kind of Iterator that can only be used once
2. The Gremlin Console iterates each Traversal for a significant (configurable) number of times

The second aspect can be prevented with the code example below. The first aspect makes the answer to your question a practical "no". Of course you can code some kind of abstraction that fulfills your needs yourself.

```
gremlin> node1 = g.V(1); null
==>null
gremlin> node1.class
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal
gremlin> contacts = node1.out('knows'); null
==>null
gremlin> contacts
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
gremlin> contacts
gremlin>
```

Comment: Additionally, you can save an ID for later use. So rather than return the vertex, you could just return its ID, and later on do `g.V(my-saved-id).out()`

Comment: what i want to know if i save a reference to a vertex by node1 = g.V(1);
can i put this in a hash-map and put the adjacent vertices in the values of the hash-map 
in other words .. can i make a adjacency list in gremlin and be able to access the node via the variable the holds the node reference .. just as it is in graph data structure

Comment: You will need to pull back all the data that you need if you want to keep an in memory data structure (a bit like a cache) that you can iterate over "offline". The two easiest ways to do this are to (a) use the `subgraph` step, which will return an actual TinkerGraph that you can iterate over (if you use the Java based clients) or (b) return a series of paths that you can iterate over later using something like `g.V(1).group().by().by(out().valueMap(true).fold())`. That would give you essentially and adjacency list for `V(1)`